# how to get cssSelector path to an Element inside Shadow-root

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Could you please help me to find the correct path to element

hatchbacks

[image]

This is java code i used ,apparently the cssSelector path is wrong

```
    WebElement shadowHost2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//vmos-flyout"));
    SearchContext shadowRoot2 = shadowHost2.getShadowRoot();
    WebElement shadowContent2 = shadowRoot2.findElement(By.cssSelector("app-vue/div/ul/li[3]/ul/li[4]/div/p"));
```

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application if it is public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
                .executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//vmos-flyout[@slot='seamless-vmos-flyout']")));
                
element.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Hatchbacks']")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you ,Now i am getting this error " org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: invalid locator"

Comment: Do you know at which line it is throwing that error?

Comment: its showing error here , may be we have to use cssSelector for shadow-roots .Unfortunately url is not public. WebElement executeshadow =shadowRoot10.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Hatchbacks']"));